# Why not infer rest of generic params?

Tags: typescript

On this code, typescript show error: `A rest element type must be an array type`

```
type B<X extends any[]> = [...X];
```

But, this code works

```
type A = any[];
type B = [...A];
```

Why?

Comment: This is a [known issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26113)

Comment: Oh, really, thank you!